# In a vector space that follows the standard definition of matrix multiplication must all matrices be linear?

Tags: linear-algebra

My motivation for this question is I am having an intuition problem with matrix multiplication.  The matrix represents a transformation and the transformation is linear in the geometrical sense if the origin stays the same and the transformation produces parallel and equally spaced line on the new coordinate axis undergoing the transformation.  I assume not all transformations are linear but is this true? While looking at a lecture on matrix multiplication it seems the professor applied the algebraic definition of linear to set up the way the matrix multiplication was defined.  Was that a sleight of  hands or is it the case not all matrix multiplication is linear ? Somewhat confused trying to figure out why matrix multiplication was defined the way it was. Thank you.

Comment: It is true that not all transformations are linear but it is only linear transformations that **can** be represented as matrices.

Comment: Multiplication by a matrix is a linear transformation.  Conversely, every linear transformation (over $\Bbb R^n$) can be represented by a matrix

Comment: Omnomonmnom ....if your statement is correct this is exactly what I am looking for!!!!!!   too good to be true....this is what has been bothering me as I work through the lectures....it shows equivalence ...the essence of the problem......

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's true - not all transformations are linear, but the way matrix multiplication is set up allows us to writr linear transformations as matrix multiplications.

Comment: Would you go so far as saying that that a linear transformation is a PARTICULAR kind of matrix multiplication ?

Comment: No. There is only one way to mutiply matrices in the usual manner. A specific linear transformation is represented by a specific matrix.

Comment: Please read Omnomnomnom comment above ...do you agree??? this is what I meant to ask !!! thank you

Answer (score 1):

There are several points raised in your question.

1. Not all transformations are linear. Yes this is correct for example a non-zero translation or a rotation of the plane about a point other than the origin.
2. Why is matrix multiplication defined the way it was. Take the matrix product $\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}$. According to the definition one multiplies rows from $A$ "into" columns from $B $ to generate the element of the product matrix. This multiplication is associative
   $$
   (\mathbf{A}\mathbf{B})\mathbf{C}=\mathbf{A}(\mathbf{B}\mathbf{C})
   $$
   You could alternatively define matrix multiplication so that rows of $A$ multiply *rows* of $B$ to generate the resulting matrix, however, this is not associative.

Incidently, one does not have to use matrices to represent linear transformations but it is convenient to do so as an aid to computation. Also, different matrices can represent a given linear transformation, depending on the bases adopted for the domain and codomain of the transformation.

Comment: Please check out my comment to Sean Robertson above....do you concur ??

Comment: goof on my part....please read Omnomnomnom's comment above...this is the essence of what is troubling me.

Comment: I agree with Omnomnomnom' comment.